# Disable keyboard shortcuts in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, keyboard-shortcuts

Usually I'm a fan of keyboard shortcuts. However, I'm also a fan of typing the first few letters of a file I'd like to find in a document list or a tree. 
Since this is automatic behavior for me, I keep forgetting that it doesn't work on Google Drive - but not before I already typed in 4 or 5 letters, which did a few things to my files already. And it was fast, so I don't even know what is it I did.

I investigated a bit on how to disable keyboard shortcuts on Google Drive, but it seems this isn't possible anymore (Gmail still has the option, but not GDrive).

Also, searching here on webapps.stackexchange.com yielded nothing. I can't be the only one annoyed by this.

Any ideas?

Comment: They've also hijacked Cmd+Left and Cmd+Right, which I rely on for back/forward in the browser.  I'd really like to get these back.

Comment: userscript (such as tampermonkey) might be the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to burst your bubble, but at least I got the answer for you.

See image below.

[image]

And for those looking for the ful list of keyboard options: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en